# Get length of child elements for each element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to iterate through a list of elements which have the ID #color-lines and a unique class for each element like so: `<div id="color-lines" class="block-2088">` The unique class is dynamically driven by WordPress's post ID so each block will be unique.

Within each div there are various numbers of `<a>` tags and I am trying to use addClass to each one depending on how many child elements there are in each div.

```
    $( "#color-lines" ).each(function(){

        var className = $( this ).attr("class");
        var anchoLink = ( "." + className );

        var n = $( anchoLink ).children().length;

        $( anchoLink ).children().addClass( "line-width-" + n );

    });
```

What I get is each `<a>` tag with the same class `line-with-n` for every div element even though there is a different number of `<a>` elements in each div.

Comment: "iterate through a list of elements which have the ID #color-lines"- stop. Id's should be unique...

Comment: ...and classes shouldn't be. (Well, they can be, but there's not much point to it.)

Comment: Id has to be unique per document. You can't have multiple elements with the same ID in the same document, or you are doing something terribly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your ID's and classes around, in other words, ID's should be unique, classes should be used on similar elements. You can write the `each()` loop for your elements with the same class:

```
$(".color-lines").each(function() {
    var n = $(this).children.length;
    $(this).children("a").addClass("line-width-" + n);
});
```

Comment: OK - The leanest way seems to be tymeJV's solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ID's` must be unique while `class` can be duplicated.

using an `id` as selector return only 1 item, so `$('#color-lines).each` loop only through the first `#color-lines`.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I got this to work: `$( ".color-lines" ).each(function(){

   var className = $( this ).attr("class").split(' ')[1];
   var anchoLink = ( "." + className );

   var n = $( anchoLink ).children().length;

   $( anchoLink + " a" ).addClass( "line-width-" + n );

  });`

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the rule that ID should be unique, what you may need to do is add a find() call on your DIV selector.  In this example I have assumed that you swapped the class and ID attribute.

```
$( ".color-lines" ).each(function(){

    $( this ).find("a").addClass( "line-width-" + $(this).children().length );

});
```